# jquery load html with js tags in div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Problem:**

I want to load external html via ajax inside a div using jquery.Its pretty easy. But in my case ,  htmls can have lots of script and css tags and `$.ajax().done()` event is fired as soon as html is loaded but it does not wait for tags to complete loading and hence js code that depends  on these tags fails.

**Objective:**

**Purpose** of this question is to know if there is any `event` that can be used to know when html and its tags have loaded fully in such cases.

**Note** that example below is a sample to explain my problem.
*Please don't advise to move jquery-ui to index as this is just to illustrate my problem.*
you can see error at console while running `index.html` that `TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function` becuase jquery ui is still loading in background.

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="siteloader">loading ...</div>​

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'dynamic.html'
            }).done(function(html) {
                $("#siteloader")
                .html(html);
                //draggable fails here
                $("#draggable").draggable();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**dynamic.html:**

```
<h1>Dynamic HTML</h1>
<h2>with big js css files</h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<style>
    .demo-description {
        clear: both;
        padding: 12px;
    }
    .ui-draggable,
    .ui-droppable {
        background-position: top;
    }
    #draggable {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.5/ace.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.18.2/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        console.log('Dynamic html loaded');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: put `$("#draggable").draggable();` in `dynamic.html` instead of `index.html` because you are loading jquery-ui in `dynamic.html`

Comment: Purpose is to know if there is any event i can use, jqueru-ui usage is just an example , it could be any js file with logic etc

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery ui in your first page (from where you are calling the ajax)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
     // load jquery ui here
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 </head>
  .....
```

Since JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute. `draggable()` (jquery ui) is being loaded in `dynamic.html` and you are using it in `index.html` which doesn't have `draggable()` function. You can load all the necessary js in index.html itself or the other way is to call `draggable()` in `dynamic.html`. I prefer to go with first.

If you have to execute script then you can have a look at [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: ui is just for example. consider it as any js file

Comment: Load he js you want to use in main page so it recognize all of the functions used from the js. Or there is a function in jquery `https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/` which will execute the script but I guess you have update you code a little bit.  Have a look at it.

Comment: JavaScript inserted via html does execute . in above example after a while , when loaded, you can see jquery-ui becomes available even in index.html. I just need to know how can i know when loading is done including tags